# How do I get salesforce access token using the REST API?

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api

How do I get salesforce access token using the REST API in exact target landing page.. Help me to do this Activity..

```
 %%[
 var @url, @clientId, @clientSecret, @result
 @clientid = ""Client_id"
 @clientSecret = "Client_secret"
 @url = "https://auth.exacttargetapis.com/v1/requestToken"
 SET @result =HTTPPost2(@url,"application/json", @clientId, @clientSecret)   
 ]%%
 %%=v(@result)=%%
```

I used this code in landing page, instead of `client_id` and `client_secret` I have given salesforce connected app `client_id` and `client_secret` but its not returning access token is this correct way to get access token from exact target landing page using OAuth 2.0.

I am getting the below error. Is this correct code for getting token from salesforce?

> **Error Message :** An expected comma is not found in the varible declaration. Script var @url, @clientId, @clientSecret, @result @clientid = "XXXXXX. XXXXXX" @clientSecret = "XXXX" @url = "XXXXXXXX/v1/requestToken" ListID: 0 Index: 50
>
> **Description:** An unexpected error occurred during the execution of the page

Comment: Refer the link https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-getting-started.meta/mc-getting-started/get-access-token.htm

Comment: Thank you responding.. i have updated question above please check once..

Comment: Use the HTTP ampscript. Your code as it is not wrapped in any backend language to communicate with the server

Comment: Please do not use images as error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use the following to request a token in AMPScript on Landing Pages, Emails and Mobile Connect:

```
%%[
VAR @httppost,@apiid,@apistatusCode,@apiresponse,@apitoken
SET @apiid = '{"clientId": "YOUR_clientId","clientSecret": "YOUR_clientSecret"}'
SET @httppost = HTTPPost2("https://auth.exacttargetapis.com/v1/requestToken","application/json",@apiid,false,@apistatusCode,@apiresponse)
SET @apitoken = Substring(@apistatusCode,17,24)
]%%
```

Where @apitoken is the Token to be used for future API calls.
Substring isn't a great way to get the Token from the Response, but it works.

Here is where you get the ClientID and ClientSecret:
[image]
Ref: https://appcenter.s1.marketingcloudapps.com

Comment: Thank you for responding .. getting thorized","errorcode":1 in response

Comment: Happy to help User321 - Double check that you have put the correct details from https://appcenter.s1.marketingcloudapps.com, including the correct Data Access rights. I've updated my answer to include a screenshot of the IDs. Are you getting the Error Code on the Token request - or when you try to use the Token?

Comment: Thank you..i am getting error when i am tring to get token

Comment: Hey @user321, I just tested my code exactly as it is above (replacing the values YOUR_clientId and YOUR_clientSecret with my details from the AppCenter, and I was able to successfully retrieve a Token. can you confirm that your "SET apiid" line looks something like this: **'{"clientId": "39458gh4875gh45h","clientSecret": "eir34rh475hgh48"}'** (fake values)

Comment: Is it Possible to get Salesforce Access Token USing AMP Script now we are getting App center token..

Answer (score 0):

You need to go the app exchange and register an app. At the end of the process you will get a Client ID and Client secret . Them you make a call to request the token which is valid for 60 minutes

Answer (score 0):

Try This.

```
POST https://auth.exacttargetapis.com/v1/requestToken
Content-Type: application/json
    {
"clientId": "YOUR_CLIENT_ID_FROM_APP_CENTER",
"clientSecret": "YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET_FROM_APP_CENTER"
}
  200 OK
{
"accessToken": "YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN"
"expiresIn": 3600
 }
```

Comment: Hi, i amgoing to write code in landing pages from ladning page we need to get access token using hhtp ampscript i tried code why iam getting error i m not sure please help on this way